# Firestore startAfter(), How to know when no more to load

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Just implemented "startAfter" for the first time. However, a bit of searching around and I cannot find an answer to an issue I have.

How best to handle when there are no more documents to load when using "start after".

Should I grab the collections total document length each time I fire a "load more" function. Check total vs current and if they are equal, disable the load more function?

If so, how do I find the total count of the collections documents?

Answer (score 4):

> Should I grab the collections total document length each time I fire a "load more" function.

No. When we create a pagination algorithm, we are always interested to load data in smaller chunks. In Firestore, we are always also interested in the size of each new chunk that we get. So basically, if the new chunk has the size that is smaller than the limit we have set, for example, 10 items per page, then that's the moment when you should disable "load more function".

So the idea is that you can request pages of data of a certain size. Here's a helpful method named `limit(X)` that can help you achieve this. So you can perform a query and get a page of size `X`. Simply continue that query with another page of size `X`, and so on. So you start on page `1`, then progress through the pages using the corresponding methods where you should specify which document was the last one on the page and then continue to get the next page until there are no elements left.

> If so, how do I find the total count of the collections documents?

Isn't about the number of documents in a collection that you have to worry it's about the number of the items you get in the next page.

Comment: Nice answer @alexmamo! If I may, I would add that to find the total count of the collections documents you should either query for the entire collection (which is not recommended obviously) or maintain a counter of documents, for example with a [distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters). But as you said, this is not needed for paginating.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure if you requested documents from a collection with a limit of 10, that only had 10 documents and you used startAfter with the last of those documents to fetch the second page, because the query returned 0 documents you wouldn't be charged any reads for that second "load more" query.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thank you Renaud for your comment. It's really helpful to know about those distributed counters.

Comment: @samthecodingman There is [a minimum of one document read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations), even if a query yields no documents

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is save the last visible document to a variable, like so

```
lastVisible = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1]
```